# Activity Background как у рабочего стола

Tags: android, activity, android-style, background, android-themes

Добрый день. Пишу живые обои, и мне нужно чтобы по двойному клику на рабочем столе загружалась activity с дополнительной информацией, при этом чтобы на заднем фоне были мои живые обои. В принципе решил проблему, сделав тему, в которой задний фон полупрозрачный, но тогда видно все ярлыки на рабочем столе, которые мешают отображению информации. В принципе я уже с этим смирился, но сегодня заметил, когда звонил будильник - в нем реализовано то, что мне нужно - мои живые обои, которые работают на заднем фоне, а сверху две кнопки, перенести и выключить. Никаких ярлыков сзади нет. Как они это реализовали?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
<style name="Theme.Shaded" parent="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```